# Static files not loading for deployed django rest framework

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have built and successfully deployed a django rest framework using gunicorn and nginx on Ubuntu 18.04. However, the static files are not being pulled up.
[Django web app without loaded static files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNmGh.png)

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name [my_server_domain_or_IP];

        #root /var/www/html;
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /static/ {
                root /home/ubuntu/myprojectdir;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
}
```

And in my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
import os
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

I have checked that DEBUG is set to False.
I have also already run `collectstatic` and the static files are located in a folder called static in: /home/ubuntu/myprojectdir/static.

Every change I tried to make in the nginx configuration, I restarted nginx with the following command: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`.

I mainly followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04), the only difference is that I edited the default nginx configuration instead of creating a new one because it wasn't deploying my django application this way.

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong and have been trying to solve it for days. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need equals sign here:

```
location = /static/ {
            root /home/ubuntu/myprojectdir;
    }
```

Instead try this:

```
location /static/ {
            root /home/ubuntu/myprojectdir;
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much !! I can't believe it was something so simple

Comment: @tidoot Sometimes it happens) Good luck then!

Answer (score 1):

Try to giving permissions to your home folder

```
chmod a+x /home/ubuntu -R
```